# Neo4j Desktop installation error "App initialization error Error: EISDIR"

Tags: windows, neo4j, network-drive, neo4j-desktop

we are fighting with a strange issue trying to install Neo4j Desktop version 1.5.9 on a Windows 11 client (local installation).

The software started once and asked for a data directory to store the database in. We used a network drive for this (Neo4j Desktop on the local Windows Program Folder for all users and the database location on a network drive). After that we got a "Project failed to create error" similar to this screen (here you see a different version but it is exactly the same error).

[image]

From that on it wasn't possible to start up Neo4j Desktop again

We deinstalled Neo4j Desktop completely. A new installation (even after cleaning up all the program fragments manually) did not solve the issue - Neo4j Desktop refuses to start up.

We checked the log files and it appears that Neo4j is still looking for the network drive set during the first installation. Even after we deleted the local neo4j files, cleaned the Windows registry of neo4j entries and ran a fresh installation the following message shows up in the log file:

```
App initialization error Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'G:<network drive path>\projects\project-3a8d9382-0884-4fc0-8489-44e182a17445' -> 'G:<network drive path>Neo4j\relate-data\projects\project-d577cc4b-8aae-4d57-8115-3c5d323cf956'
```

Even after a fresh installation Neo4j Desktop picks up this network path somehow. Does anybody have an idea which internal entries (beside from the program files) needs to be cleared to be able to start a fresh installation on the local machine?

As mentioned we have deinstalled the Neo4j Desktop, cleaned remaining files manually and even cleaned the Windows registry where we could. Unfortunately with no luck. A new installation of Neo4j Desktop on the same machine leaves us with the same situation. No startup of the Client possible anymore.

And within the log there is always an error pointing to the network drive.